# Client-only request strictly after SSR request in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have two Vuex actions that both issue an axios request. I need to call one after the other, however, the second should only be called on the client side.

The first one, let's call it `fetchContent` is going to give me an object with details about the content that I need to fetch. The second one, `fetchAd` is going to fetch an ad, and it needs to know the `id` of the content object.

Due to various constraints, the ad should only be fetched on the client side, so just doing two `await`s inside `fetch` will **not**.

I also thought about handling `fetchContent` inside `fetch` and then calling `fetchAd` inside `mounted`, but then I can't be sure by the time the page is mounted I actually have the response from `fetchContent`.

Another scenario I thought of is to just issue the `fetchAd` call from inside `fetchContent`, but there are several different variations of `fetchContent` and embedding `fetchAd` in every one of them would yield unnecessary complexity.

What's a clean, best-practice solution here?

Comment: If you call `fetchContent` from `fetch` and `await` it, then you _can_ be sure that by the time `mounted` is called that you have its response, and can therefore call `fetchAd` from `mounted`.

Comment: @RWD yes, but then `fetchAd` is still SSR - I need `fetchContent` to be SSR, while `fetchAd` to be client-only

Comment: `mounted` is only called [client-side](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#client) so `fetchAd` would not be SSR